# VB.net Mysql Joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql, vb.net-2010, join

I want to view all these fields but 3 of them are from different tables.

```
Dim sql As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT tblproduct.ProductNo, tblgenericname.genericname, tblproduct.BrandName, tblproduct.Quantity, tblproduct.PurchasedDate, tblproduct.ExpirationDate from tblproduct, tblGenericName where tblproduct.Genericno = tblgenericname.genericno, tblcompany where tblproduct.CompanyNo = tblcompany.CompanyNo and tblcompany.CompanyName like '" & cmb_com_load.Text & "'order by BrandName", con)
    Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter()
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet

    da.SelectCommand = sql
    da.Fill(ds, "rec")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "rec"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sql:

```
SELECT tblproduct.ProductNo, tblgenericname.genericname, tblproduct.BrandName, 
tblproduct.Quantity, tblproduct.PurchasedDate, tblproduct.ExpirationDate 
from tblproduct
join tblGenericName on tblproduct.Genericno = tblgenericname.genericno
join tblcompany on tblproduct.CompanyNo = tblcompany.CompanyNo 
where tblcompany.CompanyName like '" & cmb_com_load.Text & "'order by BrandName
```